# How to format the TextBox that can input only a number and also have a constant string value

Tags: vb6

I need to get values like EMPN0001, EMPN0002, EMPN0003, EMPN0000
The "EMPN" here can't be change
and the 4 digit number is in Integer
The user will only enter 4 digit number but the textfield has already a value EMPN

```
example
EMPN 0001
EMPN 0002
```

Here is my code

```
Dim Employee as String
Private Sub Text_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER_Change()    
'Text_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.TEXT =Format (Text_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.Text, )
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use MaskEditBox and set the mask as EMPN####

Comment: Thank you It's a great help

Comment: +1 And @Brent You can select this as the answer by clicking on the hollow tick mark to the left of the answer. This will turn the tick green, and indicates that this answer solved your problem.